save several key frames in one asset(pose library)
I am wondering is it possible to store or save a set of poses in one asset on asset browser.
for example: if i insert a several of key frames for walk cycle then i want to save all these key frames to use it later in only on asset not many, is it possible? and if not is there another way?
Ps: I have blender 4.0
thanks
